# AWS Lamba will not deploy .NET6 Application - Cannot find .NET6 SDK

Tags: asp.net-core, aws-lambda, deployment, .net-6.0

I have an asp.netcore3.1 application that was working fine on AWS lambda until the framework was deprecated and I had to migrate .net6.

I was able able migrate locally and run the application successfully. However I just cannot get the application to redeploy to the existing AWS Lambda function. It keeps throwing an error that:
**error MSB3644: The reference assemblies for .NETPlatform,Version=v6.0 were not found. To resolve this, install the Developer Pack (SDK/Targeting Pack) for this framework version or retarget your application. You can download .NET Framework Developer Packs at https://aka.ms/msbuild/developerpacks**

I have tried updating global.json to

```
{
  "sdk": {
    "version": "6.0.0"
  }
}
```

Any ideas on this issue?

Comment: Please make sure you have installed the .NET6 SDK. Also, which version of Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: did you upgrade your AWS lambda function runtime to .NET 6?